# Docker Containers up and running but cannot load the localhost

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I could able to run Wiki_js and MongoDB containers using docker-compose. Both are running without any errors.

[image]

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  wikidb:
    image: mongo:3
    expose:
      - '27017'
    command: '--smallfiles --bind_ip ::,0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - 'MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null'
    volumes:
      - $HOME/mongo/db:/data/db
  wikijs:
    image: 'requarks/wiki:1.0'
    links:
      - wikidb
    depends_on:
      - wikidb
    ports:
      - '8000:3000'
    environment:
      WIKI_ADMIN_EMAIL: myemail@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - $HOME/wiki/config.yml:/var/wiki/config.yml
```

This is config.yml file. I didn't set up git for this project.

```
title: Wiki

host: http://localhost

port: 8000

paths:
  repo: ./repo
  data: ./data

uploads:
  maxImageFileSize: 3
  maxOtherFileSize: 100

db: mongodb://wikidb:27017/wiki

git:
  url: https://github.com/Organization/Repo
  branch: master
  auth:
    type: ssh
    username: marty
    password: MartyMcFly88
    privateKey: /etc/wiki/keys/git.pem
    sslVerify: true

  serverEmail: marty@example.com
  showUserEmail: true
```

But I cannot load the localhost under the port 8000. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: could you share your docker compose file?

Comment: @andre updated with docker-compose file.

Comment: try to `telnet localhost 8000` on the host ?

Comment: Showed "Connected to localhost" and then show "Connection closed by foreign host."

Comment: `netstat -anpl | grep 8000` to see any process is running on that port

Comment: this is the result i got  --> tcp6    0    0    :::8000     :::*     LISTEN     12126/docker-proxy

Comment: how is accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000` ? @Cosmics

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan showing "The connection was reset" error in the browser.

Comment: can. you share the content of `config.yml`  file

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I updated the question with config.yml file

Comment: @Cosmics in config.yml, change `http://localhost` to `http://127.0.0.1` then rebuid and check `http://127.0.0.1:8000 ` again

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan getting the same issue. there is one warning when i run docker-compose. it is -> "CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file." is it the reason?

Comment: Try run `docker-compose logs` to see whether any non-fatal error/warning messages were displayed during initialization.